# Using custom control from another database

Tags: xpages

I need to use a custom control which is a simple navigation bar from another database

navigation bar is made with twitter bootstrap css framework,

why do I need to use a custom control from  another database?

because this navigation bar is going to be common to four notes Databases,

how can I implement this more efficiently?, a control that is common to four databases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Domino includes template inheritance features that allow either an entire application or a specific design element (like a Custom Control) to be updated whenever the template design changes. You could link the shared Custom Control in each of your four applications to a common template so that, if you need to make changes to it, you only have to change it in one place. You can not reference a Custom Control that *only* exists in another application; you'd have to store it in each and link the design to keep it synchronized.

Alternatively, you can use the Extensibility API to convert it to a library component. Controls of this kind can be used in any application running on a server that has the library installed. A video tutorial for this process can be found [here](http://notesin9.com/index.php/2012/04/04/notesin9-064-global-custom-controls-fixed/).